# Conditional statement in blogger template is not working

Tags: xml, blogger

In my blogger template add a conditional statement. But it is not working. It is always display **'Not equal'**

> Home url: http://abc.blogspot.in
>
> Page url: http://abc.blogspot.in/p/my-page-url.html

For testing purpose i had pasted the below code after **'`<body>`'** tag.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;p/my-page-url.html&quot;'> 
<h1>Equal</h1>
<b:else/>
<h1>Not equal</h1>
</b:if>
```

I had printed the value of `<data:blog.url/>` and `<data:blog.homepageUrl/>p/my-page-url.html` and it is same.

**updates:**

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;http://abc.blogspot.in/p/my-page-url.html&quot;'> 
    <h1>Equal</h1>
    <b:else/>
    <h1>Not equal</h1>
    </b:if>
```

//Not equal

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;http://abc.blogspot.com/p/my-page-url.html&quot;'> 
    <h1>Equal</h1>
    <b:else/>
    <h1>Not equal</h1>
    </b:if>
```

//Equal

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the above code with this

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageId == "PAGE_ID"'>
    <h1>Equal</h1>
    <b:else/>
    <h1>Not equal</h1>
    </b:if>
```

To find the **PAGE_ID** go to Pages, now click edit to open the page in Blogger post editor. In the address bar you may find something like this "pageID=**6284317258827606063**" now copy the page id and replace with the **PAGE_ID** above.

Comment: Sorry! Still it is 'Not equal'. Any idea with 'contains'. I had tried <b:if cond='data:blog.url contains &quot;p/my-page-url&quot;'> 
<h1>contains</h1>
<b:else/>
  <h1>not contains</h1>
</b:if>

Comment: @user2214646 sorry...i updated the answer... please check that

Comment: using page id is the simplest way to achieve what you want... let me know if that works for you @user2214646

Comment: PAGE_ID logic is working fine. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the '+' with 'path' without '.

Answer (score 0):

[Patternpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63314606/13363870) answer is correct. You can use this to achieve what you want.

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.url.canonical== data:blog.homepageUrl.canonical path "my-page-url.html"'>
    <h1>Equal</h1>
    <b:else/>
    <h1>Not equal</h1>
</b:if>
```